# File manager's type-ahead find not working properly in 14.10

Tags: filemanager, 14.10

If I open the file manager and start typing, then it seems the first keystroke is not registered. For example, if I type "docu" in order to select Documents, instead it registers "ocu" and selects some other directory or file which starts with these letters. Afterwards, the type-ahead feature works normally. This only happens when I open the file manager or open a new tab within the file manager. I get the same results with GNOME files, nemo, and thunar. There was no such problem in 14.04.

It's a small issue that is difficult to google, but really annoying. Any suggestions?